# App_Code folder in WAP?

Tags: asp.net

Is the App_Code folder really used anymore in Web Application Projects?  I know you used to put custom controls (not user) in there but what about in a WAP project?  Is the App_Code really used by anyone anymore in WAP or is it non existant in WAP?  I don't think a WAP project creates one by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The app_code folder is intended for "Web Site Projects" - not for "Web Application Projects."

> The App_Code folder exists for Web
>   site projects in Visual Studio 2005.
>   This folder is not typically included
>   in Web application projects.

-- and --

> By default, only class files of Web
>   application projects are compiled by
>   MSBuild when the Build Action property
>   is set to Compile. However, if a Web
>   application project includes class
>   files in the App_Code folder, those
>   class files will be compiled by the
>   ASP.NET compiler. This is true even if
>   their build action is not explicitly
>   set to Compile.

See [this article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983464.aspx) for more information.